# How do I install xulrunner for mongodb?

Tags: 11.04, installation, xulrunner

For installing mongodb i want to install these dependenciy so when i run this command

```
sudo apt-get install curl tcsh scons g++ xulrunner-1.9-dev libpcre++-dev libboost-dev libmozjs-dev
```

give me this result :

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libmozjs185-dev' instead of 'libmozjs-dev'
g++ is already the newest version.
g++ set to manually installed.
curl is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xulrunner-1.9-dev : Depends: xulrunner-1.9 (>= 1.9.0.19+nobinonly) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried setting source list and update and install but it is not happening ?

here is my source list .

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted universe

deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib


deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy-security main

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security main universe


deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main universe

deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ natty main universe
```

please suggest what can be problem , how can i install it  ?

Comment: okay fine done by installing in sequece form this link http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+for+Linux#BuildingforLinux-Ubuntu10.04%5C but want to know how it solved

Answer (score 1):

Don't install `xulrunner-1.9-dev`, it hasn't existed since Jaunty (9.04).

Comment: How to uninstall xulrunner-1.9-dev